# Intercepting requests sent by iframe

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

I am trying to intercept all web requests using by Puppeteer-Sharp but it is not working properly if the request sent by IFrame which is located on the page. For instance, After navigated this [link](https://www.rtlnieuws.nl/nieuws/video/video/5173153/een-mondkapjesplicht-de-kalverstraat-gaat-dat-werken), I clicked the video link since the video is in the iframe(maybe this is not the cause, this is only my hypothesis), the new web requests sent by IFrame did not intercept but the others were intercepted. When I checked it on the Chrome Developer Tools I was able to see what I am looking for and also more requests.

By the way, I set Request Interception as true as below:

```
 await page.SetRequestInterceptionAsync(true);
```

and I registered for the PageRequest event as below:

```
 page.Request += Page_Request
```

Is there any other setting or missing setup?